# Eclipse multiple projects to view as one in project explorer

Tags: eclipse, multiple-projects, working-set

I have downloaded a FOSS source code and built using maven. And then created the eclipse project using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. This source has number of modules and now I have multiple eclipse projects when I import them into eclipse. The issue is `Project Explorer` which already had my other projects, has become a mess due to these new multiple projects. What I want is to create something like a parent folder in `Project Explorer` and put these new projects into it.

I have tried creating a working set for this. I could group new projects with it but then I can't see my early projects there. (I only see the working set.) Is there any other way to do this? I want to see my new working set + other projects at once.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is an old post, put I figured out that Eclipse does, in fact allow you to "categorise" your projects. The basic steps are :-

- Create a working set
- Select the projects you want to be included in your working set
- Repeat the last 2 steps for all your projects.
- In the explorer view, click the down-arrow icon on the explorer title bar.
- Navigate to 'Top Level Elements' in the dropdown menu that appears
- Select 'Working Set'

EDIT: I found a handy tutorial that show you how to do it.
https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-working-sets-explained

Comment: This link is not working anymore.

Comment: @KiranJoshi, thanks for the heads up. The site changed the urls by losing the 'subdomain' portion of the articles. I updated the link above.

Answer (score 3):

Working sets is the right approach. But when you switch Project Explorer over to use Working Sets, only projects that are in a working set will show up. So, create another Working Set to contain all your "early" stuff, then in the Project Explorer view menu (little white down-triangle), choose "Select working Set..." and then select the ones you want to show up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a hierarchy of projects for Project Explorer.  I'd say create another workspace and you can always have multiple copies of Eclipse open with different workspaces.  Most days lately, I have had RAD7, RAD8, and Eclipse 3.7 going all at once.  It's handy to have multiple large monitors, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create a single folder having multiple java projects in Eclipse:

1. Create a folder in your workspace say "Test".
2. Create a java project say "TestProject" in eclipse by choosing the default location which will be the workspace.
3. Move the "TestProject" into the folder "Test".
4. Refresh the Project Explorer.
5. Now go to File >  Import... and select "Projects from Folder or Archive" option under the General section.
6. Click on Directory and choose the folder "Test" which is the one that we want to hold multiple java projects.
7. Click on Finish.
   And you should now see the folder "Test" containing java projects in Project Explorer.

I hope someone will find it useful when they need to save their java projects in Github by initializing git in that single folder containing multiple java projects.